# how to use a variable from other context in c#

Tags: c#

I just need to know on how to use variable from other blocks or context(or whatever they call it)...

I was trying to create an app installer for windows 10 using powershell but i'm just a beginner for c#...

I have 2 Buttons the browse and install, I declare the location of the file in the browse button's block and I was trying to use that variable in the install button's context.

But all I got is "The name "appFile" does not exist in the current context."

Here's my code:

```
   private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Created by Carlos Miguel Salamat","Windows App Installer");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
        file.Title = "Choose Package File";
        file.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
        file.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        file.FilterIndex = 2;
        file.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = file.FileName;

           string appFile = file.FileName;
        }
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strCmdText;
        strCmdText = "powershell.exe add-appxpackage";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText, appFile);
    }
  }
}
```

`

Comment: You need to declare appFile at a higher level, eg the form level. then it is available to other areas like below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define it to global,

```
string appFile = "";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
    file.Title = "Choose Package File";
    file.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
    file.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    file.FilterIndex = 2;
    file.RestoreDirectory = true;
    if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = file.FileName;

        this.appFile = file.FileName;
    }
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strCmdText;
    strCmdText = "powershell.exe add-appxpackage";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText, this.appFile);
}
```

Hope helps,

Answer (score 2):

The answers are obviously correct, but before blindly applying them, I would strongly advice you to look for some 101 on programming and Object Orientation. Variable scoping rules are very similar among most languages. You will find yourself in similar puzzling situations if you try to skip the basics.

Answer (score 0):

You can read & learn about it here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Might be a short answer but rather than giving you a fish you better learn how to catch it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the variable at least in the class context to access it from other methods within this class. If you need to access it from outside the class you need to make it public and add setter/getter

```
public class YourClass {
    public string AppFile {get;set;}

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Created by Carlos Miguel Salamat","Windows App Installer");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
        file.Title = "Choose Package File";
        file.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
        file.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        file.FilterIndex = 2;
        file.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = file.FileName;
            this.AppFile = file.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string strCmdText;
        strCmdText = "powershell.exe add-appxpackage";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText, this.AppFile);
     }
```

}

You could also use the Text Property from your textBox1 like this:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string strCmdText;
        strCmdText = "powershell.exe add-appxpackage";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText, textBox1.Text);
     }
```

But I would definetaly advice you to use the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

Wim, is right. You would do well breaking that type of code up into say a class called file, then just call it on the click method. That way you can reference it from other methods in a different class. Just my opinion when working with complex Objects.